# REST API service URI Not working from Postman/other REST Clients,but working fine with Workbench

Tags: community, rest-api, contentversion, workbench, postman

Am trying to Insert/Upload a File(Base64) from Rest Client by mentioning

https://mysalesforce-instance.com/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/ContentVersion
by giving Body as

```
{
"Title":"New Upload",
"PathOnClient":"NewUpload.JPG",
"ContentLocation":"S",
"OwnerId":"<My Id>",
"VersionData":"file base64 information"
}
```

Passing headers with the Authorization access token
and Content-type apllication/json;charset=UTF-8

I can able to get response from Workbench,
but when I have done this in Postman/ARC am getting ContentVersion object description like below.
but not getting successful ID. Kindly let me know is there any thing I need to do.

```
{
    "objectDescribe": {
        "activateable": false,
        "createable": true,
        "custom": false,
        "customSetting": false,
        "deepCloneable": false,
        "deletable": false,
        "deprecatedAndHidden": false,
        "feedEnabled": false,
        "hasSubtypes": false,
        "isInterface": false,
        "isSubtype": false,
        "keyPrefix": "068",
        "label": "Content Version",
        "labelPlural": "Content Versions",
        "layoutable": true,
        "mergeable": false,
        "mruEnabled": false,
        "name": "ContentVersion",
        "queryable": true,
        "replicateable": false,
        "retrieveable": true,
        "searchable": true,
        "triggerable": true,
        "undeletable": false,
        "updateable": true,
        "urls": {
            "compactLayouts": "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/describe/compactLayouts",
            "rowTemplate": "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/{ID}",
            "defaultValues": "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/defaultValues?recordTypeId&fields",
            "describe": "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/describe",
            "layouts": "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/describe/layouts",
            "sobject": "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/ContentVersion"
        }
    },
    "recentItems": []
}
```

Comment: was this ever resolved?  I just got the same issue with a custom object.  POST gave me the object description.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong HTTP method. If you perform an HTTP GET to `/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/ContentVersion`, you will obtain the response body shown.

This is the [sObject Basic Information](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_basic_info.htm) endpoint. To create a record, you should be using POST.

Comment: I Tried with Post method ,the provided response I experienced in POST method response only. Can you pls try and let me know whether it is working for you or not.Is there any configuration I need to do?

Comment: I don't use Postman, but my experience is that making an invalid POST request gets you a completely different error.

Comment: But ,When i use same Url /services/data/v48.0/sobjects/ContentVersion in Workbench with same params,am getting successfull response.but why in postman it is showing description.

Answer (score 0):

When I had the same issue, it turns out that I was pointing to the wrong endpoint url.

My initial (wrong) url endpoint was
https://{instance}.lightning.force.com/services/data/...

when it should have been

**https://{instance}.my.salesforce.com**/services/data/...

Unfortunately instead of getting a not found error, I got the object description returned.